# Combine two very similar functions that contain distinct differences

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, refactoring

I have two functions in my Node.js application:

```
retrieveIssues: function(githubAppId, pemFilePath, repoOrg, repoName, callback) {
  const octokit = require('@octokit/rest')();
  let data = null;
  gitInstallationAccessToken.genInstallationAccessToken(githubAppId, pemFilePath, (installationAccessToken) => {

  octokit.authenticate({
    type: 'app',
    token: `${installationAccessToken}`
  });

  async function paginate(method) {
    let response = await method({
      q: "repo:" + repoOrg + "/" + repoName + " is:issue" + " state:open",
    per_page: 100
    });
    data = response.data.items;
    var count = 0;
    while (octokit.hasNextPage(response)) {
      count++;
      console.log(`request n°${count}`);
      response = await octokit.getNextPage(response);
      data = data.concat(response.data.items);
    }
    return data;
  }

  paginate(octokit.search.issues)
    .then(data => {
      callback(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  });
}

retrieveEnerpriseIssues: function(repoOrg, repoName, callback) { 
  const octokit = require('@octokit/rest')({
    baseUrl: config.githubEnterprise.baseUrl
  });
  let data = null;

  // token auth
  octokit.authenticate({
    type: 'basic',
    username: config.githubEnterprise.username,
    password: config.githubEnterprise.token
  });

  async function paginate(method) {
    let response = await method({
      q: "repo:" + repoOrg + "/" + repoName + " is:issue" + " label:sdk" + " state:open",
      per_page: 100
    });
    data = response.data.items;
    var count = 0;
    while (octokit.hasNextPage(response)) {
      count++;
      console.log(`request n°${count}`);
      response = await octokit.getNextPage(response);
      data = data.concat(response.data.items);
    }
    return data;
  }

  paginate(octokit.search.issues)
    .then(data => {
      callback(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

The first accesses public GitHub, the second a private Github. Whilst there are some very distinct differences(authentication type and number of parameters passed etc), they are very similar. I was wondering if these could be refactored into a single function or if that is even a good idea. If it is possible and could improve my code how is this done?

Comment: What is the problem? Just combine these functions adding some conditions...

Comment: Don't use a `callback` parameter when working with promises and/or `async`/`await`! Just `return` that `paginate(octokit.search.issues);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, and given the amount of duplication, probably should refactor. It was a little tricky without any tests and without the ability to run the code but maybe this would do the trick?

```
retrieve: function({repoOrg, repoName, callback, octoKitArgs, octoKitAuthArgs}) {
  const octokit = require('@octokit/rest')(octoKitArgs);
  let data = null;

  octokit.authenticate(octoKitAuthArgs);

  async function paginate(method) {
    let response = await method({
      q: "repo:" + repoOrg + "/" + repoName + " is:issue" + " label:sdk" + " state:open",
      per_page: 100
    });
    data = response.data.items;
    var count = 0;
    while (octokit.hasNextPage(response)) {
      count++;
      console.log(`request n°${count}`);
      response = await octokit.getNextPage(response);
      data = data.concat(response.data.items);
    }
    return data;
  }

  paginate(octokit.search.issues)
    .then(data => {
      callback(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

// call as private github
retrieve({
  repoOrg: "",
  reportName: "",
  callback: () => {},
  octoKitArgs: {baseUrl: config.githubEnterprise.baseUrl},
  octoKitAuthArgs: {type: 'basic', username: config.githubEnterprise.username, password: config.githubEnterprise.token},
});

// call as public github
gitInstallationAccessToken.genInstallationAccessToken(githubAppId, pemFilePath, (installationAccessToken) =>
  retrieve({
    repoOrg: "",
    reportName: "",
    callback: () => {},
    octoKitArgs: undefined,
    octoKitAuthArgs: {type: 'app', token: `${installationAccessToken}`},
  })
);
```

Let me know how this looks.

Comment: That's pretty close. I can see that the `return data` in the `retrieve` function actually returns the data. Now I need to handle it. Looking at the enterprise call for now I've done this:

```
... config.githubEnterprise.username, password: config.githubEnterprise.token},
 function(data, err) {
   if(err) {
    console.log('err: ', err);
    } else {
            console.log('data: ', data);
    }
```

I'm seeing neither an error or data though. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry i don't know, like i said i have no way of running this, i just edited it and posted it. if you have any tests or a test harness or something maybe in a github gist or something. What is the function with the if statement in it doing? is it getting passed into the octokit.authenticate function?

Comment: Actually, it works when I change `callback: () => {},` to `callback:  function(data, err) { if(err) { console.log('err: ', err); } else { console.log('data: ', data); }`.

I also changed `return data;` to `callback(data)`.

Comment: I updated your answer to reflect how I changed your code to get it to work as I require. If you think there's anything wrong with what I did or if there's any way I can improve it I'd be happy to get the feedback.

Comment: If it works for you that is brilliant, I'm glad i could help. The call back functions can be anything you like i put them in as empty so that you could see what was required as i was unsure what you wanted the callbacks to do. cheers.